# How to add class to openframeworks project in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, openframeworks

I am normally a C# guy but trying to get into c++.

I made myself a new openframeworks project by copying and pasting one of the example projects and then renaming everything to my project name. (If there is an easier way, I would love to hear it)

This project has the .cpp and .h files in a sub folder called "src" which are in turn organized into  virtual folders (filters???) in visual studio.

How can I add a class to this project from within visual studio?

If I right click on the src filter in the solution explorer and hit add class. It creates the class files at the root of the project not in the src folder. I mean it does this both in the solution explorer and where it physically places the files. This is a problem because I can't include my class files in the rest of my app, presumably because they aren't in the same folder

What is the proper way to add a class file?

Answer (score 1):

When you right click on the filter (could be the "src" or a new one) and hit 'Add class', after hitting 'Add' in the first screen, in the next one you will find a [...] button besides each text input field for the .h .cpp files: with that button you can chose the folder where your files are going to be saved ('src' or any other).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a good solution but the only way I have found to do this is to add the class in visual studio, which places it in the root. Exclude the files from the project. Move the files to the src folder using Windows Explorer. Include them in the project by showing all files and then right clicking to include in project. At this point I would expect the files to be listed in the project but don't appear until I reload the project. Once the project is reloaded I then drag and drop the files into the src folder/filter